# Difficulties in exporting a PDF from draw.io

Tags: app.diagrams.net, pdf

Everytime I try to export a diagram from draw.io to pdf it just gives "error saving file" or does nothing. This happens especially when I enable the mathematical typesetting feature. When I successfully export PDF file from the diagram after many trials, the exported diagram looks different from the actual diagram in draw.io. Is there anything I can do fix this?

#### Edit

Below is the file that causes the problem (you can save it in `.drawio` file). Using the 'print' option in the File menu does not work either. For example, when I click print -> OK, nothing happens

BTW, **I am using the desktop version**

```
<mxfile modified="2019-05-16T00:49:08.927Z" host="www.draw.io" agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) draw.io/9.3.1 Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Electron/3.0.6 Safari/537.36" etag="oqa2PTnF-crdeIcZyT9C" version="10.6.7" type="device"><diagram id="zJaDm6VkeqVxXdKPE4xx" name="Page-1">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</diagram></mxfile>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to draw.io Helpdesk...

> "Huge diagrams might cause a timeout on the servers that generate the PDFs. This might result in a blank or corrupt PDF being returned..."

How big are the diagrams you are trying to export? Do you have the correct permissions to access/edit the diagrams? More info [here](https://desk.draw.io/support/solutions/articles/16000042565-draw-io-for-jira-cloud-displays-error-saving-file-insufficient-access-rights-).

It appears draw.io is aware of issues that occur when exporting as a PDF, so it might be worth trying to manually export as a PDF file via the printing dialog on Mac or Windows. 
Instructions on how to do that are [here](https://desk.draw.io/support/solutions/articles/16000059741-what-alternatives-are-there-to-the-application-generated-pdfs-).

Finally, you can also export the diagram as an XML file and reimport it in a new file to see if that helps:

> In the menu select Extras->Edit Diagram, select the text that starts and end with  tags, open a text editor, paste the XML in as a new file and save it. That file will be loadable back into draw.io using a fresh browser tab with www.draw.io loaded, opening the file from the local device where you saved it.

More details [here](https://desk.draw.io/support/solutions/articles/16000089553-how-to-save-a-draw-io-diagram-when-standard-saving-fails).

If all else fails, try contacting draw.io Helpcenter support. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. However, my diagram is not that big. Also using the 'print' option in the File menu does not quite work also. For example, when I click print -> OK, nothing happens. I will attach the file in the question.

Comment: Hmmm, that is unusual. I recommend contacting draw.io. I'll keep researching for you.

Answer (score 1):

If any one else still has this issue :

1. Export as HTML
2. Open HTML file with google chrome -> (...) three dots top right
   -> Print...  -> Save as PDF

Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem with you and have solved it now. You can download the desktop of the app draw.io here>>> https://github.com/jgraph/drawio-desktop/releases/tag/v13.7.3 ,and use the same function in desktop, it works!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I found that the problem was caused by the diagram which I thought was just one page in size, was spread over two pages ever so slightly. I amended the diagram and the export worked ok. I know this will not be the issue for everyone.